# Extjs3.2 RowEditor Field validation

Tags: validation, gridview, row, extjs3

I am working on `ExtJS version 3.2`. I have grid with `roweditor` plugin. I want to validate some of my fields while editing. I found somewhere validator
but its not working in 3.2,s o is there any alternate to `validator` in this version or any other code.

Below is my code

```
{
    header : "Payment",
    width : 120,
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'payment',
    renderer: 
           function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
               return  getToolTip(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
           },
    editor : {
           xtype : 'numberfield',
           allowBlank : false,
    },
    validator: function(value) {
           alert('value');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the validator as follows for EXT JS 3.2 with the row editor plugin

```
{
                            header : "Payment",
                            width : 150,
                            sortable : true,
                            dataIndex : 'payment',
                            renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {

                                 return  getToolTip(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
                                } ,
                            editor : {
                                xtype : 'textfield',
                                allowBlank : true,
                                validator: function(val) {
                                     var re = new RegExp("^[A-Z0-9, ]*$");  // Use of Regular expressions for validation
                                     if (val.match(re)) {
                                        return true;
                                     } else {
                                         return "Invalid Value, AlphaNumeric, comma and space allowed ";
                                     }
                                   }
                            }
                        },
```